# How does one properly import large JSON files into MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I've got an extremely large JSON file (200,000 rows) that I'd like to import to MySQL Workbench for manipulation and extraction into tables. As far as I can tell, it seems the way to do this is to import the file as a single cell in a table which has the JSON data type. My multiple attempts to import this have been met with errors, as follows.

- Importing via LOAD DATA INFILE returns Error Code 1290, the secure-file-priv one, even though I've disabled that setting and placed the file in the correct location anyway just to be safe
- Importing via Table Data Import Wizard returns "Can't analyze file. Please try to change encoding type. If that doesn't help, maybe the file is not: json, or the file is empty.

Figuring it was safe to assume that these errors had something to do with the outrageous size of this file, I attempted this with a much smaller JSON file (20 rows), and encountered the following issues:

- Importing via LOAD DATA INFILE returns Error Code 1290 again, even though I've taken the steps listed above
- Importing via Table Data Import Wizard *seems* to work at first, however spits out "0 Records imported" at the end, leaving the table untouched.

I'm only moderately experienced with MySQL and hardly experienced at all with handling JSON data, so I'm betting this is an obvious error caused by my inexperience in this topic. Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would honestly use Python or some other programming language to process the JSON into individual records, and INSERT each record.

Comment: The new MySQL Shell (mysqlsh) has a very powerful parallel import utility that will very quickly bulk load JSON, CSV, or TSV files. If you are not tired to Workbench this may be a better way to load your data.  See https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2019/08/parallel-table-importer-in-mysql-shell.html for an example

Comment: Did you find a way to import json file in Workbench?

Comment: I ended up doing it in a very roundabout way with a python script, where I would use Pandas to read_json from the source (in my case, an FTP address), then use json_normalize to get it into the format I wanted, then use to_sql (which I think is from the SQLalchemy python package) to insert that as a table to my sql database. So basically what Bill suggested above. I wasn't able to find an easier and more automated way to do it.

Comment: You don't. You import them into the *database*, with commands *issued from* MySQL Workbench, or something else. Clarity please.